# Force Reset of Bootstrap Classes for PrimeNg OrgChart

Tags: primeng

I'm trying to build an organization chart using PrimeNG controls, and I have it all about working, but I'm having some trouble with the connector lines stylings. Basically, the connector lines that show lateral relationships aren't appearing.

[image: Org Chart Image]

It appears that this is due to the 'border-style' and 'border-width' properties of _reboot.scss coming from the bootstrap css in my angular application. If I remove these properties via Dev Tools...

[image: css class removal]

Then the lines show up appropriately.

[image: Org Chart w/ lines]

So I figured I'd go see what the 'default' value of those are and just override those th / tr / tbody / td/ etc classes on the local file to be whatever the default is. The issue is, I can't find that default.

Can anyone help me figure out either A) what that default value should be that I can set this to, or B) how to tell this file specifically to ignore the CSS coming from _reboot?